# How to delete those blank in the end

Tags: powershell

In the *Powershell*,I can get the item in current folder with this command

```
ls | ft name >list.txt
```

But if I open the `list.txt` with *Microsoft office Word*.Then we can see there are may blank character in every line

[image]

So how to delete those blanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's `Format-Table`s job to properly arrange data in columns you shouldn't be surprised about the trailing spaces.
BTW redirecting it's output creates UTF16 files with a BOM (which Msword can interpret)

Similar to uSlackr's version:

```
(gci).Name | sc list.txt
```

Using PowerShell also on Linux/MacOS I tend to avoid the OS specific aliases but use the PowerShell aliases - so no `dir`/`ls` but `gci` or `Get-ChildItem`

Answer (score 0):

Powershell is applying some formatting to your table including padding it.  This command will cleanup the file a bit but it loses the header.

```
ls |foreach {$_.ToString()} |set-content list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @uSlackr said, Powershell appends unneccessary formatting when you use `Format-Table`. Here's my workaround:

```
ls | ft name > list.txt 
# this writes the original results to your file

$lines = Get-Content list.txt 
# this gets the results of list.txt 

$lines | ForEach-Object{ echo $_.ToString().Trim()} > list.txt
# and this goes through each line and removes the leading and trailing space before writing
the result to list.txt
```